# Force mount.cifs to use specific kerberos ticket

Tags: cifs, kerberos

TL;DR I want to force `mount.cifs` (or `smbclient`) to use specific ticket (e.g. `cifs/server@DOMAIN2` instead of `cifs/server@DOMAIN`).

### Long Story

I have two smb servers (both are windows): `server-a` and `server-b`. I have no problem mounting a share from `server-a`:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //server-a.domain-a/share /mnt/a -o "sec=krb5,cruid=$UID"
# uses cifs/server-a@DOMAIN-A
```

However, trying to mount a share from `server-b` results in error (emphasis mine after `sudo smbclient...`):

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs //server-b.domain-b/share /mnt/b -o "sec=krb5,cruid=$UID"
mount error(126): Required key not available
$ sudo dmesg|tail
[7267002.391319] CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -126
[7267002.391504] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -126
$ sudo smbclient //server-b.domain-b/share
ads_krb5_mk_req: smb_krb5_get_credentials failed for **cifs/server-b.domain-b@DOMAIN-A** (Server not found in Kerberos database) <- note wrong domain
cli_session_setup_kerberos: spnego_gen_krb5_negTokenInit failed: Server not found in Kerberos database
session setup failed: SUCCESS - 0
$ klist |grep "Default principal"
Default principal: user@DOMAIN-A
```

### My diagnosis

mount.cifs mistakenly uses `DOMAIN-A` (my principal domain) instead of `DOMAIN-B`. Hence, I want to force it to use the right ticket.

1. **Can I force mount.cifs or smbclient to use specific ticket? If so, then how?**
2. What are rules for ticket selection in mount.cifs / smbclient?
3. How can I check which ticket is being used for connection?

Comment: It turned out that both smbclient and mount.cifs that come with ubuntu 14.04 trusty used the right tickets